# cakephp code to subtract two columns inside for each loop

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am selecting two different columns from two different loops.

I want to subtract the values coming in the first for each loop and the values coming in the second for each loop from each column and display the result.

I need the subtraction inside for loop because I have multiple values and I need to display subtraction of all the values.

I am working on cakephp 1.3

**Code:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <?php
      foreach($co2cont as $co2result) {
          $t1 = $co2result['u_data']['totalco2_emmission'];
      }

      foreach($co2modecost as $co2mode) {
          $t2 = $co2mode['u_data']['CO2totalcharge'];
      }
   ?>
   <td><?php echo $t3 = $t1 - $t2; ?></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show your resultant array. and show us what is expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to subtract the datas of foreach loops.if yes Try this,

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <?php
          foreach($co2cont as $key => $co2result) {
          $t1 = $co2result['u_data']['totalco2_emmission'];
          $t2 = $co2modecost[$key]['u_data']['CO2totalcharge'];
          $t3 = $t1 - $t2;
          echo "<td> $t3</td>";
          }
          ?>

 <td>&nbsp;</td>

 </tr>
</table>
```